# Get angular component generated HTML by node.js

Tags: node.js, angular

This is a architectural\design\best practice question:
I'm having an angular2+ based application which amongs all send a rendered HTML
(using the nativeElement.outerHTML of an html element reference - ElementRef) to the server and as a response, receive HttpResponseMessage.
I would like to do it asynchronous, meaning - running it as a scheduled task.
I would like to use node.js to do so. node.js has an option of making a request to an html file. The problem is that due to the angular routing system, I can't get html generated page, just by supplying the url.
Is there another option\idea of doing so ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ViewChild` decorator and after that you can get the HTML with outerHTML property. e.g:

app.component.html:

```
<div #someHTML>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
</div>
<button (click)="test()" >Test</button>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('someHTML') someHTML: ElementRef;
  test(){
    console.log(this.someHTML.nativeElement.outerHTML)
  }
}
```

Now with the html you can send the request to the server.

Comment: I'm aware of it - the problem is that this is a solution for application context. It doesn't give me a solution. My colleague is trying to do it now with a framework called phantomjs - hopefully that will be the solution.